# 3-dimensional light up cube, # of rows/cols/diags in/on a 4 × 4 × 4 cube

Tags: probability

[image]

Imagine a 3-dimensional cube (much like a 4 × 4 × 4 Rubik's cube) except the planes of the cube cannot be twisted individually and instead of faces with different colors, it is clear (see thru) but with a single light in each of the $64$ little cubes contained within the $1$ big cube.

The $64$ lights are connected to $64$ switches, all of them initially turned off.  We now turn on a light by choosing a switch uniformly at random, toggling it (so that the light turns on if it was off, and turns off if it was on), and repeat this lighting process for a total of $32$ times.

At the end, we therefore have at most half of the $64$ lights lit — but the actual number is likely to be less, since some lights may be toggled several times.

**I'd like to confirm the answers to the following five questions:**

$1$. What will be the average number of lights on after all $32$ random numbers are processed sequentially, meaning that the corresponding lights were toggled properly from them, possibly multiple times each?

$2$. At the end of the lighting process, we want to know what is the probability that only $1$ complete row, column, or diagonal will be illuminated.  That is, $4$ adjacent/connected lights that complete one of those.  It may help if you think about and answer question 3 first.

$3$. How many possible complete unique/distinct rows, columns, and diagonals are there in/on the cube?  Remember they can go thru the cube, not just along the faces.  Also, they can be on the inner planes such as planes $2$ and $3$ (of $4$). They must be collinear.  You cannot go around a corner for example and get $4$ in a row.  All $4$ lights must lie in a line segment of length $4$ with length (in this context) meaning # of adjacent lights illuminated in a collinear fashion.

$4$. What is the ideal number of lights on that will give us the highest probability of having exactly $1$ complete row/col/diag?

$5$. How many random lights (minimum) need to be on to guarantee that at least $2$ complete rows/cols/diags are illuminated?  That is, the probability of exactly $1$ complete row,col,diag becomes $0$.

---

I used computer simulation and got the following results so far:

1. On average about $20.4$ lights will be on.
2. I get about $31.89$%.  The result is somewhat surprising to me because of all the possible ways to get $1$ complete row/col/diag, you would think out of $20$ or so lights (on average), you would get multiple of those more often.  My simulation program is even telling me that getting $8$ complete is even possible, but very unlikely.  I don't know what the max is, maybe $20$ or so if all $32$ lights stay lit and they just happen to be perfectly placed for maximum lit rows/cols/diags.
3. I counted $76$ distinct complete rows, columns, and diagonals (so far) of length $4$.
4. It appears that the ideal # of lights on is $23$, which gives about a $39.5$% chance of exactly $1$ complete row/col/diag. $22$ was a close 2nd with a $39.3$% chance. $24$ came in 3rd with a $38$% chance.
5. I think the minimum is $47$.  The algorithm I used is very simple and very fast. Obviously you cannot have any $4$ in a row, col, or planar diagonal, so I simply started with $48$ (of $64$) lights on, making sure to turn off $1$ in each row, col, and planar diagonal (but not checking 3D diagonals).  My simulation program told me I had $3$ complete "lines" at that point.  I then checked to see if I could get only $1$ line lit by testing each of the $48$ on lights by turning them off one at a time then putting them back on before the next test.  That dropped it to $2$ lines illuminated.  I then looped thru combinations of $2$ on lights (there are $48 \choose 2$ of them which is only $1128$).  That dropped it to only $1$ line lit.  F.Y.I. my program told me there were $27$ two light combos that (when turned off) dropped it to only $1$ line lit.  So with that info, we just take the penultimate distinct # of lit lights we tried (which was $47$) and that is our answer.

The correct answer for Question $2$ depends on getting Question $3$ correct, so that is why I am asking for some help, because I want to get this exactly right.

For the diagonals, I counted $2$ per face, so that is $12$ facial diagonals (imagine an X shape on each face), $12$ inner planar diagonals which are Xs also but on planes $2$ and $3$, twisting the cube in all $3$ dimensions.  I also count $4$ inner "3D" diagonals that go thru the "heart" of the cube.

Can someone please help me confirm these numbers?

Comment: These are 3 separate questions.

Comment: Yes but they are all related so I asked them together here.  Anyone can answer any subset of the questions if they think they have a good answer/method.  I am working on them myself but having some difficulty and could use some help,  I made this scenario up myself and was curious if the math is a "bear" to compute the answer to question $2$.

Comment: What is the source of this problem?

Comment: I made this up myself from "scratch" but it was motivated from a 4x4 lottery ticket then I extended that idea into 3D and added the lights.  I am not getting the "hard" answers I am looking for.  I am getting formulas and methods instead.  I was hoping for actual numbers for answers.

Comment: @David Click on Edit to edit your post. In the editing bar (where it allows you to bold, italicize, etc.,) click on the one where it looks sort of like a picture frame/image of a mountain. It will then allow for you to upload a picture file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Question 1:

This one is actually pretty easy.

It helps to start by considering a single light.
The number of times the light is toggled is [binomially distributed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), with parameters $n = 32$ and $p = 1/64$, and the probability that it ends up being lit at the end of the process is the sum of the probabilities that it is toggled an odd number of times, i.e.:

$$P = \sum_{k=1}^{16} f(2k-1;32,\tfrac1{64}) = \sum_{k=1}^{16} {32 \choose 2k-1} \left( \frac1{64} \right)^{2k-1} \left( 1-\frac1{64} \right)^{33-2k},$$

where $f(k;n,p) = {n \choose k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$ is the probability mass function of the binomial distribution.  A laborious but straightforward evaluation of the sum, best carried out by a computer, then yields the result:

$$P = \frac{932357239278482603486754898815444262218545775615}{2923003274661805836407369665432566039311865085952} \approx 0.318972$$

Now, by the [linearity of the expected value](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity), the expected number of lit lamps is simply the total number of lamps times the probability of each lamp being lit, i.e. $64 P \approx 20.41423$.

*Ps.* I did the calculation in [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/), but any language that has an arbitrary-precision rational type will do — or you can even use floats, if you only want an approximate numerical value.  Here's the code I used:

```
f(k,n,p) := binomial(n,k) * p^k * (1−p)^(n−k);
P: sum(f(2*k-1 , 32 , 1/64), k, 1, 16);
float(P);
float(64 * P);
```

---

#### Question 3:

The third question, is a simple exercise in 3D visualization and enumeration:

- For each of the three axes, there are 16 columns running parallel to the axis for a total of 3 × 16 = 48 columns.
- For each of the three axes, there are also 2 × 4 = 8 diagonals running perpendicular to that axis (from one edge of the cube to the opposite), for a total of 3 × 8 = 24 diagonals.
- Finally, there are 4 "inner diagonals" running from one corner of the cube to the opposite one.

Thus, the total number of ways you can arrange four sub-cubes in a row in a 4 × 4 × 4 cube is 48 + 24 + 4 = 76.

---

#### Question 5:

For this question, we can equivalently ask for the minimum number $n$ of unlit lamps needed to get at least one unlit lamp in every line of four lamps except one.  The minimum number of lit lamps needed to guarantee at least two fully lit lines of four lamps is then $k = 64 - n + 1$.

An upper bound for this is given by the fact that each 4×4×1 plane must contain at least four unlit lamps (as otherwise it would contain at least one fully lit row and one fully lit column).  Thus, it is clear that at least 16 unlit lamps are needed to keep the number of fully lit lines below two.  Thus, $n \ge 16$, and so $k \le 49$.

Conversely, the following configuration (`0` = off, `1` = on; each square is one slice of the cube) demonstrates that $5 + 4 + 4 + 5 = 18$ unlit lamps can be arranged to leave only one fully lit line of four lamps (an inner diagonal from top left to bottom right):

```
1100  0111  1011  0110
1011  1110  1101  0111
1110  1011  0111  1101
0111  1101  1110  1011
```

Thus, the minimum number of lit lamps needed to guarantee at least two fully lit lines of four is at least 47, and no greater than 49.

In fact, it turns out that the configuration above is optimal (although not uniquely so), and that the minimum number of lit lamps needed to guarantee at least two fully lit lines of four is $k = 47$.  I have confirmed this by first generating all the 1636 possible 4 × 4 planes with 4 or 5 unlit lamps and 0 or 1 fully lit lines, and then searching all possible combinations of such planes for a combination with at most 17 unlit lamps and at most 1 fully lit line.  No such combination was found, proving that $n = 18$ unlit lamps is the minimum needed to achieve less than two fully lit lines.

(The trick that made the search feasible was making sure to prune early any partial configurations containing two fully lit lines or two planes with 5 unlit lamps, since no such combination can appear in an $n=17$ solution.  This pruning allowed me to only check 40,478,800 full cubes, which was easily doable in a few minutes even on my old laptop.)

*Ps.* The configuration above was found by noting that there are only 10 ways to arrange 12 lit lamps and 4 unlit ones on a 4 × 4 plane without getting any fully lit rows, columns or diagonals.  It further turns out there's a way to stack four such planes into a cube in such a way as to leave only three inner diagonals (and no other lines of four lamps) fully lit:

```
1101  0111  1011  1110
1011  1110  1101  0111
1110  1011  0111  1101
0111  1101  1110  1011
```

Turning off two more lamps then leaves only one of the diagonals fully lit.

---

#### Question 2:

Your even-numbered questions seem, at least to me, quite a bit harder than the odd-numbered ones.  I don't have an analytical solution for them, but I did run a stochastic simulation of my own to confirm your results.  It does appear that the probability of getting exactly one fully lit line of four lights with 32 toggles is about $0.318951 \pm 3\times10^{-6}$ (95% confidence interval, [calculated using a normal approximation](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval) from 100 billion trials).  The proximity of this value to the probability of a single lamp being lit seems like a rather remarkable coincidence, but I can't really see any way it could be anything *but* a coincidence.

(The maximum number of fully lit lines of four lamps I observed in my simulation was 16, but the theoretical maximum obtainable is at least 20, achieved by lighting all 32 lamps in one half of the cube.  I suspect that's the best one can do with 32 toggles, although I haven't proven that.)

---

#### Question 4:

As for this question, my stochastic simulation confirms your result that 23 lights is optimal, with a probability of $0.3945 ±0.0001$ of getting exactly one line of four lit lamps.  For randomly toggled lamps, as in your first question, it appears that the optimum is either 36 or 37 toggles, both of which give a probability of $0.3297 ±0.0001$; I'd need to run more trials to tell if there's any difference between them, and if so, which way.

Interestingly, the expected number of lit lamps is only about 21.8 for 36 toggles, or 22.1 for 37 toggles, about one lamp short of the optimal fixed light count of 23, showing that the variance and higher moments of the light count distribution also play a role.

Comment: Actually, my first arrangement had 40 lit lamps, not 30; that was a silly mistake.  But I managed to improve it by two, based on the arrangement you posted.

Comment: @David: Uhm... but I have a counterexample right there, showing how to arrange 42 lights so that there's only one line of four.

Comment: @David: I managed to narrow the answer to question 5 down to between 47 and 50; see edited answer above.

Comment: Ilmari, my original "hunch" of $48$ seems like a good guess then.  When I have more time later, I will code your new matrix and help verify it for correctness.  Gotta love computers for tedious counting problems ("on paper").  Also, I think a mathematical proof of this type of question would be interesting.  Can a "stochastic simulation" be used as a mathematical proof?

Comment: In principle, that'd work, but the problem is that just the number of combinations of 47 lit lamps is ${64 \choose 47} = 1{,}379{,}370{,}175{,}283{,}520$. That makes naïve brute force search a bit impractical (although just barely feasible, if you have enough spare computers lying around). I do think, however, that with some clever optimizations it should be possible to reduce the search space enough to make it practical. (Ps. I got the upper bound down to 49, by realizing that 15 unlit lamps must always leave at least three fully lit lines of four.)

Comment: The optimization I was mainly thinking of was precomputing the 4×4×1 planes with 3, 4, 5 or 6 unlit lamps and 0 or 1 fully lit lines. Any cube with only one fully lit line can only contain at most one plane with such a line, and thus all the other planes must contain at least 4 unlit lamps. For 17 unlit lamps, that means we can have at most one plane with 6 unlit lamps, or two with 5. That should leave a small enough number of combinations to easily check by brute force.

Comment: @David: I just ran an exhaustive search, and can confirm that the answer to question 5 is 47.

Comment: Impressive, nice work. I will type into my program and try to confirm. I wonder if it would have been easier to start with $48$ (since that is exactly $3/4$ of $64$), and just have the program turn off $1$ lit light at a time, looking for a drop from $(2+)$ complete lit lines to only $1$. If none were found, then reinitialize to $48$ and drop all combinations of $2$ lit lights (leaving $46$ on). That might work if a "winning" $46$ matrix can be made from the initial $48$ matrix minus some $2$ light combination. $48 \choose 2$ (=$1,128$) cases is a very small number for a computer to simulate.

Comment: Check out this link to a $4$x$4$x$4$ lighted cube controlled using an Arduino.  I wish they would show all $76$ "lines" one a a time.  It is amazing that the # of combinations of lighting $32$ of the $64$ possible lights is almost $2$ quintillion (almost $2$ * $10^{18}$) which is about $10$% of all possible $2^{64}$ combinations of lights. There are many of these videos on YouTube but I liked the music on this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r1cjHSGuNTU

Comment: Ilmari, thank you for your assistance on these $5$ questions.  Your analysis and explanations were very informative and gave me a deeper understanding of this interesting set of questions.  Of course they could be extended to larger cubes, but then the code needed to check it may become much longer (depending on the language used).  For example what if we instead had an $8$x$8$x$8$ cube?  I find the math, algorithms, analysis, speed of simulation, visualizations... all very interesting for problems like this.  I awarded you the +100 bounty and appreciate all your hard work on this.

Comment: Just F.Y.I., to get the optimal $23$ lights on to give the highest chance of getting exactly $1$ "line" lit requires $40$ random toggles. Also, no matter how many (large number of) random toggles you do, the # of lights on will "settle" to $32$ which is half. I did $100,000$ iterations of $1,000$ random toggles and my simulation program is telling me $32$ lights should be lit on average. When I ran the simulation, the minimum I got (per iteration) was $16$ and the max was $48$.  I wonder what is so special about those numbers.

Comment: Also, I see a way to get $21$ "lines" lit with $32$ on lamps.  Fill the entire front face (that is $16$ lights and $10$ "lines"), then fill the rest of the top, ($12$ more lights gives $9$ more lines), then on the left side, fill the 2nd row from the top ($3$ lights and $1$ line), then finish the diagonal on the side face ($1$ light, $1$ line).

Comment: @David: Yes, the mean number of lights lit will converge to 64/2 = 32 as the number of flips tends to infinity. You can see this from the fact that, if the number of lights currently lit is less than 32, a random flip is more likely to increase it, whereas if it is greater than 32, a random flip will most likely decrease it. By similar reasoning, one can even calculate the stationary distribution of the number of lights lit after a large number of flips. I don't think there's anything very special about 16 and 48, except that they're about the same distance from 32.

Answer (score 4):

**Question 1**

This is a simple Markov chain.

Let $o_i$ be the number of lights ON at step $i$, then

$$o_{i+1}=\begin{cases}
o_i-1,&p=\frac{o_i}{64}\\
o_i+1,&p=1-\frac{o_i}{64}\\
\end{cases}$$

And $o_0=0$

You can build the matrix for this (I'm not going to) and solve for 32 steps.

**Question 2**

For 4 specific lights in row, calculate the chance that each of them is "hit" an odd number of times and note how many of the 32 shots each combination uses up (hint: it can be $4, 6, \dots,32$).

Then for all other rows, calculate the chance that at least 1 of the bulbs is hit an even number of times (including 0) and allowing for the fact that some bulbs are common with the illuminated row.

**Question 3**

From each face there are 16 rows/columns. There are 3 independent faces. Therefore there are 48 rows/columns.

Diagonals that are 4 long can only start from the corners. There are 2 in each 1x4 block. There are $4+4+4$ of these. 24.

Plus there are 4 diagonals that go from corner of the cube through the "guts" to the other corner.

$48+24+4=76$

Comment: I like the idea of using a Markov Chain for the first question - it's quite elegant. Though, it would probably be easier just to calculate the probability that a given light is on, and multiply by $64$ (which works because of the linearity of expectation), but not nearly as enlightening.

Comment: The advantage of the Markov chain is it can be extended to answer Question 2. Your idea is much easier for Question 1 - wish I had though of it!

Comment: @Dale M, how do you get only $3$ diagonals?

Comment: There are 3 diagonals with 4 lights - if you are willing to consider diagonals with less than 4 lights then there are more

Comment: There are 4 "full" diagonals that cross from one corner of the cube to the opposite one, not 3. If you also consider "semi-diagonals", where one of the three coordinates is constant, there are $3\cdot2\cdot4=24$ of those.

Comment: Right - my mistake